# VBA - Application.CalculationState always xlPending

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to ensure that all calculations are performed in the workbook, I had situations were formulas were not calculated when opening the excel file due to slowness on computer.
This is the code I have right now:

```
Public LOCAL_PARAMETERS_WORKBOOK As Workbook
Public LOCAL_PARAMETERS_WORKSHEET As Worksheet

application.ScreenUpdating = False
application.DisplayAlerts = False
application.EnableEvents = True
application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Set LOCAL_PARAMETERS_WORKBOOK = Workbooks.Open(StrPathFile, True, True)
Set LOCAL_PARAMETERS_WORKSHEET = LOCAL_PARAMETERS_WORKBOOK.Sheets("Business Process Data Flow")

LOCAL_PARAMETERS_WORKBOOK.Worksheets("DynamicPath").Calculate
If application.CalculationState <> xlDone Then CalculateFormulas

LOCAL_PARAMETERS_WORKSHEET.Calculate
If application.CalculationState <> xlDone Then CalculateFormulas
```

This is one part of a function, it's required to calculate first Sheet "Dynamic Path" and only then we can calculate Sheet "Business Process Data Flow" since the second is dependent of the first.
From what I checked if I do `application.Calculate` this will force calculations in all open workbooks to be done or retype `application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` then `application.CalculationState` will be `xlDone`.

But if I do `worksheets("").Calculate` the `application.CalculationState` is going to stay always `xlPending`, `CalculateFormulas` is a simple function with a counter and checks if `application.CalculationState = xlDone` and if not then it's going to perform `application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))`.

Is there an explanation why if I just do Calculate at sheet level the `application.CalculationState` doesn't change, and is there another solution that could be implemented here to help fix my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug with the `Application.CalculationState` when it shows `xlPending` even after calculation is complete. It manifests particularly when you have volatile functions in the workbook.

You can go around by using a class I created a few years ago. You can find it [here](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FastExcelUDFs/blob/master/Code%20Modules/ExcelAppState.cls).
If you copy code then make sure you don't copy the attribute lines (1 to 9). Otherwise I suggest you download the repo [ZIP](https://github.com/cristianbuse/VBA-FastExcelUDFs/archive/refs/heads/master.zip) and import the `ExcelAppState.cls` file.

Once you have the class, you can use it like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    Dim app As New ExcelAppState
    
    'Do stuff
    '...
    
    app.WaitForCalculations maxMilliSecondsToWait:=10000 '10 sec - or whatever timoeout you need
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey Christian,

Thank you very much for your input, it helped reach to a better solution but the class you created was impressive. Your WaitForCalculations is pretty close to what I created for CalculateFormulas but from reviewing your code what brought for my attention was SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).

Instead of focusing on full sheet but just on SpecialCells that contained formulas and force them to calculate then application.CalculationState was already xlDone, so for me was perfect solution that didn't cross my mind

Comment: Glad you found it helpful!